# javascript not running in php program

Tags: javascript, php

i have following java script in my php program for Given integers n, l and r, find the number of ways to represent n as a sum of two integers A and B such that l ≤ A ≤ B ≤ r. and my code is...

```
<script>
function count(n, l, r) {
var result = 0;
for(var a = l; a <= r; a++){
    for(var b = a; a <= r; b++){
        if(a + b == n){
            result++;
        }
    }
}
return result;
}
</script>
<?php
echo "<script>count(6,2,4);</script>";
?>
```

and i want to run this code on page load and call a function count() on load and give output. i don't know what to do.

Comment: add your all of php file content to question

Comment: Why would JS ever run in PHP...? That's like telling somebody to speak German in English.

Comment: i change my code but now it's continues running not showing any output.

Comment: @JonStirling, verstehe ich nicht ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to `echo` content that you want written to the resulting page.

Right now you're trying to run Javascript *in* your PHP script which makes zero sense.

Comment: i change my code but now it's continues running not showing any output.

Comment: Obviously. Where did you write any code that is supposed to output anything? I suggest you do some tutorials on Javascript or PHP (by themselves) before trying to use both at once.

Answer (score 0):

take a look how to get onload event https://stackoverflow.com/a/807895/1074179 or you can add jquery lib to your code and then do like https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: i change my code but now it's continues running not showing any output.

Answer (score 0):

you can't run directly a HTML tag tag inside a php script.
You must have to print or echo that html. 
for example if you want print `<h1>Hello World</h1>` 
then you have echo the html as `<?php echo "<h1>Hello World</h1>"; ?>`
like this you have write `<?php echo "<script>alert('hi');</script>";?>`

Comment: Change your code to:<script>
function count(n, l, r) {
var result = 0;
for(var a = l; a <= r; a++){
    for(var b = a; a <= r; b++){
        if(a + b == n){
            result++;
        }
    }
}
return result;
}
</script>
<?php
echo "<script>count(6,2,4);</script>";
?>

Comment: i change my code but now it's continues running not showing any output.